# Appending nodes to a nested Javascript Object in recursive manner

Tags: javascript, algorithm, recursion

I have a nested javascript object which I use as a graph. Each node in my graph has a static structure. Each node has two types of child nodes `true/false`. And they can have many child nodes associated with it ( not a Binary Tree ).

[image]

```
var directedGraph = {
        "sms_in": {
            "metaType": "",
            "data": {"parents": [], "args": {"values": {}, "keys": []}, "return": ["message", "address"]},
            "true": {
                "A": {
                    "metaType": "",
                    "data": {"parents": [], "args": {"values": {}, "keys": []}, "return": ["message", "address"]},
                    "true": {
                        "C": {
                            "metaType": "",
                            "data": {
                                "parents": [],
                                "args": {"values": {}, "keys": []},
                                "return": ["message", "address"]
                            },
                            "true": {},
                            "false": {},
                            "prototype": {}
                        }
                    },
                    "false": {
                        "B": {
                            "metaType": "",
                            "data": {
                                "parents": [],
                                "args": {"values": {}, "keys": []},
                                "return": ["message", "address"]
                            },
                            "true": {},
                            "false": {},
                            "prototype": {}
                        }
                    },
                    "prototype": {}
                }
            },
            "false": {},
            "prototype": {}
        }
    };
```

In my actual program, Whenever I draw a `div` in my `html` page I create a node for that div. The Id's will be generated in dynamic way ( In the above example I have used A,B,C).

That is why I need a way to add nodes to the graph in a recursive manner.

```
var pushNodeById = function (parentId, bool, childId, childNode) {

            for(key in directedGraph){

                if(key == parentId){
                    directedGraph[parentId][bool][childId] = childNode;
                }else{
                    //make the recursive call
                }

            }

        };
```

Can anyone help me to complete the above function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following function can be used to create each node

```
var mapIds = {};
function Node(obj){
  $.extend(this,obj);
   this.true = {};
   this.false = {};
   this.addChild = function(id,prop,obj){
    var temp = new Node(obj);
    mapIds[id] = temp;
    this[prop][id] = temp;
    return temp;
   }
   this.addTrue=function(id,obj){
    return this.addChild(id,"true",obj)
   }
   this.addFalse=function(id,obj){
     return this.addChild(id,"false",obj)
   }
   this.getById = function(id){
    return mapIds[id];
   }
}
```

Now creating tree dynamically is easier

```
var tempObj = {whatever:{}};
var tree = new Node(tempObj);

var A = tree.addTrue("A",tempObj)

A
.addTrue("B",tempObj)
.addTrue("G",tempObj);

A
.addTrue("C",tempObj);

var D = A.addTrue("D",tempObj);
D.addFalse("F",tempObj);
D.addTrue("E",tempObj);

//Now Add to C -->False -> H,I, K
var C = tree.getById("C");
C.addFalse("H",tempObj)
C.addFalse("I",tempObj)
C.addFalse("K",tempObj)

JSON.stringify(tree);
```

You can add children to each node with **getById**.

Comment: Since the question was tagged `javascript` but not `jquery` you should probably explain what the `$.extend()` function does, or use a pure js alternative.